# How to specify a location for text in a graph plotted by Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I would like to plot a graph of actual and predicted values with Python after doing a regression. I used the following codes. However, the text "R^2=0.91" is placed on the right hand side and crossing the second Y axis. Is it possible that I change its location? Thanks a lot.

```
text = 'R^2=0.91'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colorsMap = 'jet'
cm = plt.get_cmap(colorsMap)
cNorm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(yhat), vmax=max(yhat))
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=cm)
ax.scatter(Y_test, yhat, c=scalarMap.to_rgba(yhat), s=2, alpha=0.7)
scalarMap.set_array(yhat)
fig.colorbar(scalarMap)
ax.annotate(s=text, xy=(max(Y_test)-2, max(yhat)-1))
ax.set_xlabel('Actual')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
# add diagonal line
ident = [np.min(Y_test), np.max(Y_test)]
plt.plot(ident, ident, color='red')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are setting the location of the annotation in `ax.annotate` using the `xy` argument. If you want to change the location you can simply change the value to the argument to something different (e.g. `xy=(min(Y_test) + 2, min(yhat) + 1)`).